# Angular MatCardHeader : position mat-card-avatar on the right

Tags: css, angular-material

```
<mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
            <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card-header>
```

This places the mat-card-avatar on the left, are there any configuration in the mat-card-header that allow to move the avatar to the right end of the header

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @matsch we have to use flex-direction with reverse

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-card-header{
        flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
}
    
::ng-deep  .mat-card-avatar{
    width: 10%;
}
        
::ng-deep  .mat-card-header-text{
   width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way because if you see their [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/card/card-header.html) for `mat-card-header` They place *avatar* first and then *text*.

```html
<ng-content select="[mat-card-avatar], [matCardAvatar]"></ng-content>
<div class="mat-card-header-text">...</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

You have to override styles manually. Since it is a flexbox you can override it easily without changing HTML like this.

```html
<mat-card-header class="mat-card-header-avatar-right">
  <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
  <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card-header>
```

```
//SCSS Version
.mat-card-header-avatar-right {
    justify-content: space-between;
    &::ng-deep {
        .mat-card-header-text {
            margin-left: 0 !important;
        }
    }
    .mat-card-avatar {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

```css
//CSS Version
.mat-card-header-avatar-right {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mat-card-header-avatar-right ::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.mat-card-header-avatar-right .mat-card-avatar {
  order: 1;
}
```